# Python directory copy using shutil

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below code:

```
import shutil
import os
def copy_files(file_path, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    try:
        if os.path.isdir(src):
            shutil.copytree(src, dest, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(src, dest)
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Receiving below error when executing code:

```
 shutil.copytree(src, dest, symlinks, ignore)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 177, in copytree
 os.makedirs(dst)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
 mkdir(name, mode) 
 OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '


File path: /etc/ /var/tmp/
it works cp -r /etc/ /var/tmp/
```

Python2.7 I am using

Answer (score 2):

Probably you get this error because the destination directory already exists. From the documentation of `copytree()`:

> The destination directory, named by dst, must not already exist;...

Try calling `shutil.rmtree(dest, True)` before `shutil.copytree()`.

`cp` does not fail if destination exists: it just overwrites it.